# Generate ER Diagram with view permissions

Tags: oracle, database-design, oracle-12c

Currently my environment that I'm working with is using Oracle DB 12 and I have been granted view permission only.

The issue is that the ER diagram that is given to me is not complete and sometimes retrieving data from different tables can be a challenge and time-consuming.

Therefore, is there any easier way that I could generate the full ER diagram myself or at least the relations with the current permissions I have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used [SchemaSpy](http://schemaspy.org/) and it worked flawlessly.

Comment: I build a project using schemaspy unde the hook https://github.com/krismorte/database-diagrams